# Javascript add to string with each function call

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have the following situation where I have a function `f` which takes an argument `input`.

I want to be able to have `f` such that it satisfies the following output:

`f('l') --> fl`

`f() --> fo`

`f()('l') --> fol`

`f()()('l') --> fool`

`f()()()('l') --> foool`

I thought this would be achievable with:

```
function f(input) {
  let str = 'f'
  if (input) {
    return `${str}${input}`
  }
  str = `${str}o`
  return f()
}
```

However this ends up in an infinite loop. I also tried having `f` return a function, but this too does not work.

How can I write `f` in order to get my desired output while keeping the function stateless?

Comment: `return f` instead of `f()`

Comment: That would return a function and not a string

Comment: If you return a string, can you do `f()()()('l')`?

Comment: You can't mix the ability of returning a string and returning a function at the same time, you have to choose. I suggest you to use a generator to be able to get the next value after calling x times the next value. Have a look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*

Comment: @Rajesh What I mean is if I return `f` then the result of the function call `f()()()()` is simply `Function: f`. If I call `f()()('l')` then result is `fl` and not what I want

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/181327/13522

Comment: `f() == "fo"` and `f()('l') == "fol"` are not both possible.

Answer (score 1):

In JS you can even achieve this dualitiy of a function also "being" a String. Yet this is nothing you should ever use in production code.

```js
const f = function _f(prefix){
  const toString = () => prefix;
  return Object.assign(function(suffix="o"){ 
    return _f(prefix + suffix);
  }, {
    valueOf: toString,
    toString
  });
}("f");

console.log(""+f('l'))
console.log(""+f())
console.log(""+f()('l'))
console.log(""+f()()('l'))
console.log(""+f()()()('l'))

let foo = f()();
let fool = foo("l");
console.log(""+foo("l"));
console.log(""+fool);
console.log(""+foo("bar"));
console.log(""+fool("bar"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function f(input) {
  let str = 'f'
  var o = function(suffix){
    if(suffix)
      return str + suffix;
    str += "o";
    return o;
  }
  return o(input);
}

console.log(f('l'))
console.log(f()('l'))
console.log(f()()('l'))
console.log(f()()()('l'))
```

Comment: This does not work for `f()`, which returns a function

Comment: that is not possible with recursion. We cannot predict it whether another call is made or not. To achieve it you can call like this `f('o')`

Comment: OP asked for a *stateless*  function.

Comment: @Bergi Yes it is stateless. The function does not uses any external state. Each call creates a new function with previously computed string. Any number of call to original fn will not affect its state.

Comment: `str` is *internal* state. If it was stateless, you could make it `const`.

Answer (score 0):

`f()` can not return `fo`, it has to return a function. To get `fo` you need to call f like `f()('')`.

Try this:

```js
function f(input, acc) {
    acc = acc || 'f'
    if (input === undefined) {
        return function(a) {
            return f(a, acc + 'o')
        }
    }
    return acc + input
}

console.log(f('l'))
console.log(f()(''))
console.log(f()('l'))
console.log(f()()('foo'))
```

Comment: I need to be able to call it in the way I mentioned in my question

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> f() --> fo
> ```

That is impossible if `f()`'s return value is also callable as a function. I think you must be misremembering the detail of where you got this (since the rest if familiar, not unique to this question). Similarly, some of the other examples have the wrong number of `o`s for how this is normally formulated.

> How can I write `f` in order to get my desired output while keeping the function stateless?

I don't think you can, but you can do it such that any particular function involved has no *changing* state:

```js
function f(prefix, letter) {
  if (prefix && letter) {
    return prefix + letter;
  }
  prefix = prefix ? prefix + "o" : "f";
  return function(letter) {
    return f(prefix, letter);
  };
}

console.log(f()("l"));     // "fl"
console.log(f()()("l"));   // "fol"
console.log(f()()()("d")); // "food"
```

In that, `f` is stateless, and the state that the function `f` returns closes over (when it returns a function) never changes.

Answer (score -1):

As I suggest you in comments, you should better use generators to get each value after each call.

```
function * f(input) {
    for(const character of input) {
        yield character;
    }
}
test = f('hello world');
test.next(); // {value: "h", done: false}
test.next(); // {value: "e", done: false}
test.next(); // {value: "l", done: false}
test.next(); // {value: "l", done: false}
test.next(); // {value: "o", done: false}
test.next(); // {value: " ", done: false}
test.next(); // {value: "w", done: false}
test.next(); // {value: "o", done: false}
test.next(); // {value: "r", done: false}
test.next(); // {value: "l", done: false}
test.next(); // {value: "d", done: false}
test.next(); // {value: undefined, done: true}
```

As this, you just have to call the next function each time you need and concatenate the result.value each time.

Here more docs about generators : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function

Comment: I need to be able to call the function in the way I demonstrated in the question.
thanks for pointing me to generators though ;)

Comment: I understand but, again, you can't have a function which return you a function or a string, dependings on if you have added parenthesis after or not.