# JavaScript function in a function

Tags: javascript, function

I have tried to get this q but without any success...
The task is to build a function by this conditions:

```
// b('m') -> 'bm'
// b()()('m') -> 'boom'
// b()()()()('m') -> 'boooom'
```

That is my try:

```
var b = (a) => {
    var counter = 0;
    var times = counter += 1;
    var d = (a, o, times) => {
        var o = 'o'.repeat(times);
        return ('b' + o + a);
    };
    return d();
};

console.log(b('m'));
```

Comment: Y h n a a q....

Comment: Can you think of how you’d make an object where `o.value() === 0`, `o.add().value() === 1`, `o.add().add().value() === 2`, and so on?

Comment: I didnt get your question

Comment: @Ofirshukrun I mentioned that "you have not asked a question". I though you were so in rush saving to type a `question` word so that I shortened all words in a phrase to save even more time!

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/181327/13522

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript add to string with each function call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48184589/1048572)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As another variant of what naomik and NinaScholz proposed, you could avoid the extra optional argument, and use the `this` context (in ES6) to store a number primitive value that tracks how many `'o'` characters to produce:

```js
function b(a) {
    return a ? 'b' + 'o'.repeat(+this) + a : b.bind((+this||0)+1);
}

console.log(b('m'));
console.log(b()('m'));
console.log(b()()('m'));
console.log(b()()()('m'));
```

The string is only composed when `b` is called with a (truthy) argument: that string is a `"b"` followed by a number of `"o"` characters (determined by `this`) and finally the argument (i.e. `"m"` in the actual calls). If `this` is not defined (or is the global object, in non-strict mode), the count of `"o"` is considered to be `0`. This happens when `b` is called immediately with an argument (no chaining).

When `b` is called without argument, the function itself is returned, but with a `this` bound to it that has been increased with `1`. NB: so it is not actually the function *itself*, but a bound variant of it.

Answer (score 5):

You need to return a function when the input is not `'m'` – returning `d ()` is not returning a function, it's returning the result of a *call* to `d`

Here's a way you can do it using an optional parameter with a default value

```js
const b = (a, acc = 'b') =>
  a === 'm'
    ? acc + a
    : a => b (a, acc + 'o')

console.log (b ('m'))
console.log (b () ('m'))
console.log (b () () ('m'))
console.log (b () () () ('m'))
```

And another way using continuation-passing style

```js
const b = (a, k = m => 'b' + m) =>
  a === 'm'
    ? k (a)
    : a => b (a, m =>
        k ('o' + m))

console.log (b ('m'))
console.log (b () ('m'))
console.log (b () () ('m'))
console.log (b () () () ('m'))
```

Some people complain about things they don't understand - here's the same function using imperative style

```
function b (a, acc = 'b')
{
  if (a === 'm')
    return a
  else
    return a => b (a, acc + 'o')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could return use [`Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) and use a temporary `this`.

```js
function  b() {
    return arguments.length
        ? (this.value || 'b') + arguments[0]
        : b.bind({ value: (this.value || 'b') + 'o' });
}

console.log(b('m'));
console.log(b()('m'));
console.log(b()()('m'));
console.log(b()()()('m'));
```

Answer (score 0):

function b must return itself binded to `number + 1` if it was called with no params. and return a string `bo.(n times).om`. 
b is initially binded to 0.

```
let b = (function boom(number, value) {
    if (value === 'm') {
        return 'b' + 'o'.repeat(number) + 'm';
    }
    else {
        return boom.bind(null, number + 1);
    }
}).bind(null, 0); // number value is initialized to 0

console.log(b()()('m')); // boom
```