# How can this chaining be achieved in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

`f()()('x') // foox`

`f()()()()('x') //foooox`

I tried to return nested functions but unable to get desired result.

Comment: So the last one is always `x`?

Comment: @Jack Bashford No, whatever is passed as an argument.

Comment: I'm so confused at what you're trying to do.. And how you're trying to do it.

Comment: I'm confused too, it is a trick question.

Comment: @Wimanicesir why would it be weird? It's a rather classic infinite curry. In this case it's super simplified - termination condition is an argument is passed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing a function f which would satisfy the following test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51686541/writing-a-function-f-which-would-satisfy-the-following-test) and [JavaScript function in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48253672) and [javascript function rules with multiple parameter braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56549874)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a counter variable and return a function if the variable is not defined.

```js
const f = (a, c = 0) => a ? "f" + "o".repeat(c) + a : b => f(b, ++c);
console.log(f()()("x"));
console.log(f()()()()("z"));
```

ES5 syntax:

```js
function f(a, c) {
  c = c || 0;
  if (a) {
    return "f" + "o".repeat(c) + a;
  } else {
    return function(b) {
      return f(b, c + 1);
    }
  }
}
console.log(f()()("x"));
console.log(f()()()()("z"));
```

Comment: there are two issues 'console.log(f()('d')()("x"));' will throw and error. Also function name is hardcoded, so it'll always be 'f'.

Comment: You only have to change `f` twice within the function declaration @RupinderKour - and if you wanted that output, you should have placed that in your question. This answer solves your original problem, which was any number of `()` then a character.

Comment: @RupinderKour "*'console.log(f()('d')()("x"));' will throw and error.*" this isn't part of the requirement you specified. So this isn't an issue but a completely different requirement. You should best lay out *all* expectations before asking a question.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a function that returns function or result based on passed argument assuming that only last call have an argument passed.

```js
function f() {
  let os = ''

  return function again(x) {
    os += 'o'
    if (!x) return again;
    else return `f${os}${x}`;
  }
}


console.log(f()()('x'))
console.log(f()()()()('x'))
console.log(f()()()()()()('Y'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could return a function for more than one call of the function and implement a `toString` method to get the final string.

```js
function f(v = 'o') {
    var s = 'f' + v;
    function g(v = 'o') {
        s += v;
        return g;
    };
    g.toString = function () { return s; };
    return g;
}

console.log(f()());                // foo
console.log(f('it'));              // fit
console.log(f()('x'));             // fox
console.log(f()()('b')('a')('r')); // foobar
```