# javascript function rules with multiple parameter braces

Tags: javascript

How would you write a function that is like this

```
f()()

f('it') == fit
f()('x') == fox
```

I have

```
function f(s){
  return "f"+s;
}
```

Comment: Where is the `o` in `fox` coming from?

Comment: not sure - its the test cases they have here. I've not seen functions called like this before

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript add to string with each function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48184589/javascript-add-to-string-with-each-function-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to discern what you're looking for not only from your question, but also from your comments. It looks like every string begins with `'f'`, and each empty bracket-pair appends an `'o'`. Finally, a non-empty bracket-pair appends its argument.

I actually think this is a cool metaprogramming challenge.

This should work:

```js
let f = (str, depth=0) => str
  ? `f${'o'.repeat(depth)}${str}` // If given param, terminate
  : str => f(str, depth + 1);     // If no param, return func

// "fit"
console.log(f('it'));

// "fox"
console.log(f()('x'));

// "fortress"
console.log(f()('rtress'));

// "football"
console.log(f()()('tball'));

// "foooooool!!!"
console.log(f()()()()()()()('l!!!'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have only 3 required outputs and no additional behavior requirements explained. Hence, the simplest approach would be:

```js
let f = arg => 
  arg ? 'f' + arg : arg => arg ? 'fo' + arg : '';

console.log(f()()); // ''
console.log(f('it')); // 'fit'
console.log(f()('x')); // 'fox'
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a very strange function to want, but you can do it by having your named function return an anonymous function if you didn't get a parameter the first time:

```
function f(s, str) {
  if(typeof str === "undefined") {
    str = "f"
  }
  if(typeof s === "undefined") {
    return function(t) {
      return f(t, str + "o")
    }
  } else {
    return str + s;
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought of that -- ok its passed 2 tests

Comment: This misses the first example, `f()()`, which should return an empty string i believe.

Comment: failed -- f()()('bar')  == foobar

Comment: @TheOldCounty Okay, that gives me a hint as to what they really want. Hold on, and an edit is coming up.

Comment: a recursive function as such

Comment: @TheOldCounty Now it should work for that test case too.

Comment: this is close - but failed ---- (function() { const g = f()(); const h = g()(); return g('l') + ' ' + h('l'); })() -- output === fool fooool ---- comes out currently as fooool fooooll

Comment: Okay, that means it needs to not reuse a single closure per call to `f`. Another edit coming up.

Comment: @TheOldCounty How about now?

Answer (score 0):

You could return a function for more than one call of the function and implement a `toString` method to get the final string.

```js
function f(v) {
    var s = 'f' + (v || 'o');
    function g(v) {
        s += v || 'o';
        return g;
    };
    g.toString = function () { return s; };
    return g;
}

console.log(f()());                // foo
console.log(f('it'));              // fit
console.log(f()('x'));             // fox
console.log(f()()('b')('a')('r')); // foobar
```

Comment: this is close - but failed ---- (function() {
  const g = f()();
  const h = g()();
  return g('l') + ' ' + h('l');
})()  -- output === fool fooool   ---- comes out currently as fooool fooooll

Answer (score 0):

Haha I saw this problem the other day, I used function currying:

```js
var f = s => s ? `f${s}` : (g=o=>e=>e?`f${o+e}`:g(o+'o')) && g('o') 

console.log(f('x'))
console.log(f()()('l'))
console.log(f()()()('bar'))
```